# How to resolve data must be a dataframe issue in R

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, maps

I am new to R and I am trying to create a basic world map and I have tried a number of methods but my latest trial has given me a new error.

```
install.packages("mapdata")
install.packages("maps")
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
df1 <- data(world2MapEnv)
p <- ggplot(data = df1,
            aes(x = long, y = lat,
                group = group, fill = region))

p + geom_polygon(color = "gray90", size = 0.1) + guides(fill = FALSE)
```

I am getting an error under the first ggplot that says:

```
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character vector. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How do I resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The value of `world2MapEnv` does not contain any map data. That tells you which environment variable stores the path to map data. I'm not sure why are you are trying to plot that. Maybe you are following a guide that's out of date? Maybe you want `df1 <- map_data("world")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot already has map data stored. A basic map with ggplot can be drawn with this code:

```
 world_map <- map_data("world")
 ggplot(world_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
 geom_polygon(fill="lightgray", colour = "black")
```